# Example of an open A and a closed B s.t. one of A, B is not connected

Tags: general-topology

I have to find an example of an open subset A and a closed subset B such that $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are connected, but where one of A, B is not connected.

I have tried the following:
Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ be the topological space. Now let $A=(0,1)\cup (2,3)$, which is open and let $B=[1,3]$, which is closed. We have that:
$A\cup B = (0,3)$ and $A\cap B = Ø$
Which are both connected, but A is not connected.
But then I realised that my professor does not consider Ø as being connected, so my example does not hold anymore…
Can somebody help me find an example that holds?

Comment: You're pretty close; what about $A=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ and $B=[1,3]$?  (Yes, I realize that's OP's example!). In which case $A\cup B = (0,3]$ and $A\cap B = (2,3)$.